How is traversal is working on hashsets and hashmaps?
I realize we can use a for loop to iterate over elements of hashset. e.g.
Set set = new HashSet();

for(Object object : set) {
    String element = (String) object;
}

I am not able to figure out how it internally works?
It makes sense in case of arrayList because elements are stored one after the another. So iterator has the reference to first value and then we can use hasNext() and next() to iterate over all the elements. But in case of hashsets and hashmaps how does it work?
What chatgpt/gemini replied:

When we create a hashset/hashmap buckets are assigned that are mapped to hashcodes. Lets say collision techniques are also in place. When we iterate, iterator go over all the buckets fetch the elements and then performs an equality check.
It compares the retrieved element with the original elements you added using the equals() method.

It kind of makes sense, but I didn't get this equality check part. Why is this required? I assume these assigned buckets are exclusive to the hashset, so why not printing all the elements in bucket?

if chatgpt/gemini replied that, you must ask it/they why; the official documentation does not state so - I cannot find that equality check in HashTables iterator (which is used by the HashSet)- that check is necessary when searching elements of the HashSet or keys of the  HashMap (Maybe I just missed it: source)

If you want to know how iteration of a HashSet works internally ... read the source code.  You can find the OpenJDK source code to browse online, or download it.  The easiest place to start is Github.

The simple version is that the iterator scans the primary hash table array, and for each array "bucket", it traverses the linked list (or binary tree) that holds the bucket's entries.  And note that a HashSet is actually a HashMap on the inside.  The details are Java version dependent.

StephenC said the details are Java version dependent. Also, the details are implementation dependent. As a Set, HashSet  iteration order is  undefined; any order can happen, and may vary. To quote the Javadoc: “It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.”.

If you're asking ChatGPT about programming questions, you have much bigger problems than figuring out how hash iteration works.

@LouisWasserman what's wrong with asking chatGPT about programming questions?

As with every subject, it's more likely to make something up than to tell you anything useful.

Whenever it has been quoted in a Stack Overflow question as you have, it has been complete nonsense.  I wouldn't ask it for the time of day.

seems like the AI got confused: for retrieving/finding an element in the Hash*, it must do an equality check, not just rely on the hash code; but for iterating the Hash*, no equality check is needed/done (neither the hash code)
